# Saving files from one uploader class to another uploader class using Carrier wave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload, carrierwave

How do i save image files to an uploader class in carrier wave without the use of a form?

I want to instead use an existing image that's already in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's a model called image and the uploader is mounted as carrierwave:

```
image.carrierwave.store!(File.new("/tmp/image.png"))
image.write_carrierwave_identifier
image.save
```

store! accepts a File, IOString or Tempfile.